# MSHTML editing - changing the text selection color

Tags: c++, delphi, webbrowser-control, mshtml, designmode

I use `MSHTML` (`TWebBrowser` control) in Design (edit) mode. I use `TEmbeddedWB` but slowly moving away from that component and implementing my own interface. When a block of text is selected, so when typing into the editor and then selecting a block of text it is in black color for the background color.

Instead I'd like to use blue.

I know that it has something to do with the selection range but not sure how to modify it in designer mode. The code below is of course when it is not in design mode.

```
    IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = document.selection;
    IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
    if (range != null)
        {
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, "0000FF");
        }
```

Any ideas? Do I have to use event sinking? Or maybe `QueryCommandValue`? I tried some things with `HiliteColor` without success yet (according to Mozilla documentation this is not supported by Internet Explorer).

I use C++ Builder or Delphi, but code example in any language is welcome, I can (probably) translate it.

Comment: With CSS you can use https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_text_selection.asp. With that in knowledge, you chould be able to change it using some javascript command.